# Assigning an Azure AD Group permissions to a OneDrive For Business file via some API

Tags: azure, sharepoint, permissions, office365, onedrive

I have successfully been able to share a OneDrive for Business file with a group using the Sharepoint CMOS API.

Like this:

```
   context.Load(listItem, l => l.HasUniqueRoleAssignments);
   context.ExecuteQuery();
   if (!listItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
   {
       listItem.BreakRoleInheritance(true, false);
   }
   var group = context.Web.SiteGroups.GetByName(groupName);
   context.Load(context.Site.RootWeb, w => w.RoleDefinitions);
   context.ExecuteQuery();

   var roleTypeKind = readOnly ? RoleType.Reader : RoleType.Editor;
   var role = context.Site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions.FirstOrDefault(rd =>     rd.RoleTypeKind == roleTypeKind);


   var roleDefCollection = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(context) { role };
   listItem.RoleAssignments.Add(group, roleDefCollection);
   context.ExecuteQuery();
```

But the problem is that group belongs to SiteGroups which is really local to one user. So if I have an Azure AD Group I cannot access it using the Sharepoint API.

I can find an Azure AD group using the GraphClient API like this:

```
var azuregroup = activeDirectoryClient.Groups
                    .Where(g=> g.DisplayName.Equals("groupname"))
                    .ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage.ToList().First() as Group;
```

But how do I grant that group access to the file using an/any API ? It should be possible since it is possible in the OneDrive for Business UI.

It is not possible doing this

```
listItem.RoleAssignments.Add(azuregroup, roleDefCollection);
```

because the first parameter to Add has to be a Principal which the azuregroup is not.

Hope anybody can help - I have searched the internet for countless hours.